# How to get current anti-distraction focus in macos with bash?

Tags: macos

How to get current [focus](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-a-focus-to-stay-on-task-mchl613dc43f/mac) in macos with bash?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you'll get better advice on the Mac specific section of StackExchange. Please delete here and repost to https://apple.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: It's a programming-related question and on-topic here, but I agree that OP is more likely to get an answer to this on Apple.SE.

Answer (score 1):

See the article "[Help a Mac Automation Find Focus](https://sixcolors.com/link/2021/11/help-a-mac-automation-find-focus/)". There is a link to a gist. In the Apple terminal user guide, "[Automate tasks using AppleScript and Terminal on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/automate-tasks-using-applescript-and-terminal-trml1003/mac)" may also help.